# jQuery Datatable delete row function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Here is a function for jQuery datatables which deletes all rows which contains tree in the table with the id testtable.

```
function deletedatarow() 
    {
    var oDatatables = $('#testtable').dataTable();
    $("#Testtable tr td").filter(function () 
        {
        var x = "tree";
        return $(this).text() === x;
        }).closest('tr').each(function() 
        {
        oDatatables.fnDeleteRow(this);
        });
    };
```

But this function is very slow on a big html side and i dont want to delete all rows with tree or treeapple which contains tree.

Is there a quicker function which only deletes a datatable row which contains exactly the value "tree"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function deletedatarow()
{
    var oDatatables = $('#testtable').dataTable();
    $("#Testtable").find("td").filter(function(){
        var x = "tree";
        return $(this).text() === x;
    }).closest('tr').each(function(){
        oDatatables.fnDeleteRow(this);
    });
};
```

or you can try this with `:contains`:

```
function deletedatarow(){
    var oDatatables = $('#testtable').dataTable();
    $("#Testtable").find("td:contains(tree)").closest('tr').each(function(){
      oDatatables.fnDeleteRow(this);
    });
};
```

[Selector optimization](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/) is the way to boost up some operation in js as being said that dom is slow.